# VS 2017 Xamarin Remote iOS Simulator Hangs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am running a fully updated version of VS 2017 Enterprise, on Windows 10, and building an app that's been around for a while.  The Mac is remote and the build runs just fine.  When I debug/run the app with remote simulator turned off, the iOS simulator on the Mac starts and works correctly.  If I check "Remote Simulator to Windows" and launch the debugger, the simulator windows opens on my PC but never becomes responsive.  The following log looks normal but it's hanging:

```
Checking host configuration for connecting to 'ObjExMac'...
Checking host configuration for connecting to 'ObjExMac'...
Host 'ObjExMac' is configured correctly
Starting connection to 'ObjExMac'...
Starting connection to ObjExMac...
Starting Broker 1.1.6.120 in port 57224...
Starting connection to 'ObjExMac'...
SSH connection to 'ObjExMac' has been established...
Starting registered Agents: Build 4.8.0.760, IDB 4.8.0.760...
Starting Xamarin agent: Build 4.8.0.760...
Starting Xamarin agent: IDB 4.8.0.760...
Starting Agent Build 4.8.0.760...
Starting Agent IDB 4.8.0.760...
Agent Build 4.8.0.760 is running
Xamarin agent: Build 4.8.0.760 started
Agent IDB 4.8.0.760 is running
Xamarin agent: IDB 4.8.0.760 started
Starting registered Agents: ...
The Agents have been started successfully
Performing server validations against 'ObjExMac'...
Validating Xamarin iOS compatibility between local and remote versions...
Validating Mac operating system version compatibility...
Validating Xcode license state...
Performing server validations against 'ObjExMac'...
Connection to 'ObjExMac' completed successfully
Starting Simulator to launch App...
The Simulator has been started to launch App...
```

Then the process stops.  The simulator window is totally unresponsive on my PC and no simulator window appears on the Mac.  Visual Studio is responsive (I can stop the debugger) but the app never loads and runs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `...Mac is remote...` What is the connection speed and how long are you waiting...

Comment: Try to delete the app from your simulator and reinstall it , delete `bin` and `obj` folder under your application also.

Comment: Tried that. Tooling seems to be unstable and complex in general.  I am skipping it and using VNC to connect to the mac